# Can we remove the Napoleon tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I can't see any reason the [napoleon](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/napoleon) tag would ever be relevant on this site, most questions related to Napoleon would most likely be better fit on History.SE anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's safe and uncontroversial to remove tags that are used by a single *closed* off-topic question. Often this is an indication that questions about such a tag are off-topic.

My only reason for *not* doing so is that it would bump the question to the frontpage, which isn't all that useful. In this case, just deleting the question would be a better option – this would also remove the tag. I actually cast a delete vote on this question last week when I was cleaning up some off-topic tags and I see someone else added a second vote today, so if one or two more votes are added the question and tag will be removed.

Comment: Didn't realise no questions would delete the tag, I was the second vote. So we'll leave it to the community then. Thankyou.